# Spring Boot map .jsp URL to Rest Controller

Tags: spring, rest, jsp, spring-boot, controller

Due to some legacy code restrictions, I need to map some urls that end in .jsp to a specific rest controller and return json data using Spring Boot.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl/blah/blah/download.jsp", method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public String getFile(@RequestParam("id") String operation, @RequestParam("filename") String filename) {
```

However this is not mapping correctly, i get an error 404 when trying to access this url. Any suggestions? Unfortunately I am stuck having to redirect this jsp in this way and it's not an option to do it any other way for now.

Comment: what is the url you are trying to reach this endpoint?

Comment: well in this case it would be localhost:8080/applicationcontext/someurl/blah/blah/download.jsp

Comment: what about requestParams?

Comment: localhost:8080/applicationcontext/someurl/blah/blah/download‌​.jsp?id=dsf&filename=asdf

Comment: I registered a new Servlet with the url mapped and it is working now

Comment: Hi! Could you please share how you did it? I have something similar to this, which I need to keep the legacy url that has .jsp extension in the url ( the end of the url, e.g. https://form.com/forms.jsp) when use spring boot, do you need to use web.xml to map the customized servlet? Do you need to define a custom servlet listener and filter too? How do you map it?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

On your `Main Class` you need to add:

```
@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainClass.class);
    }
```

and in your `application.properties` this:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

With it you map where your JSP pages will be so Spring will know where to look for them.

Comment: I have no jsp pages in this particular app. It is just a bunch of spring boot webservices. Where one service needs the ability to intercept jsp page requests.

Comment: The answer is not relevant